# What is this manga about a student who doesn't want his diploma?

Tags: silver-spoon

Does anyone know of this manga? I also tried to search with Google Image Search but nothing of relevance was found.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is this picture from? How do I use Reverse Image Search to find the source of an anime/manga image?](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21618/where-is-this-picture-from-how-do-i-use-reverse-image-search-to-find-the-source)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This panel is from [*Silver Spoon*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_Spoon_(manga)), chapter 92, page 13. Okawa is at a graduation ceremony and is refusing to accept the diploma, causing others to force him into taking it.

[image]
      *Image credit: MangaReader*